# Filter record based on config values in U-SQL

Tags: u-sql

I have two csv files -
1] Contains column - firstName,lastName,age
2] Contains single column - id1, id2, id3
These 3 id fields contains different number.

Now from the first file I want to output only those record where age contains all the ids from id1.

For e.g. @inputfile = EXTRACT firstname string, lastname string, age int 
    FROM @inputfilepath USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows : 1);

```
@configfile = EXTRACT id1 int, id2 int, id3 int FROM @configfilepath USING 
Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows : 1);

@outputresult = select * from @inputfile where age IN (select id1 from 
@configfile);

OUTPUT
@outputresult
TO "/outputpath/output.csv";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the inner join:

```
@result =
    SELECT i.* FROM @inputfile AS i
    INNER JOIN @configfile AS c
    ON i.age == c.id1;
```